# pushing data to an array in php 5.3 vs 5.5

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm a stumped with this problem.  I'm getting no error messages.  My code works when I test locally (php 5.5).  The server my company uses is php 5.3.3.  My code does not work on the server.  When I do a var_dump I get an empty array.  Locally my array populates with data from my SQL db.

Here is my code.  I think my syntax is correct, but at this point I'm not sure.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$get_result = $db->query($sql);

$events = array();

foreach ($get_result as $row) {
    echo $row['event'] . '<br>';

    $date = $row['d1'];
    $ymd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

    $date2 = $row['d2'];
    $ymd2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2));

    $date3 = $row['d3'];
    $ymd3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date3));

    $date4 = $row['d4'];
    $ymd4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date4));

    $date5 = $row['d5'];
    $ymd5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date5));
    if ($row['approved'] == 'yes') {
        if ($row['d1'] != '0000-00-00') {
            $events[] = array('id' => '' . $row['id'] . '',
                'date' => '' . $ymd . ' ' . $row['start'] . '',
                'title' => '' . $row['event'] . '',
                'description' => '' . $row['descrip'] . '',
                'startTime' => '' . $row['start'] . '',
                'endTime' => '' . $row['end'] . '',
                'url' => 'event_details.html?id=' . $row['id'] . '&data=events',
                'location' => '' . $row['addy1'] . ' ' . $row['addy2'] . ' ' . $row['addy3'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ' ' . $row['state'] . ' ' . $row['zip'] . '',
                'eventUrl' => '' . $row['event_url'] . '',
                'subName' => '' . $row['subName'] . '',
                'subEmail' => '' . $row['subEmail'],
            );
        }
        if ($row['d2'] != '0000-00-00') {
            $events[] = array('id' => '' . $row['id'] . '',
                'date' => '' . $ymd2 . ' ' . $row['start'] . '',
                'title' => '' . $row['event'] . '',
                'description' => '' . $row['descrip'] . '',
                'startTime' => '' . $row['start'] . '',
                'endTime' => '' . $row['end'] . '',
                'url' => 'event_details.html?id=' . $row['id'] . '&data=events',
                'location' => '' . $row['addy1'] . ' ' . $row['addy2'] . ' ' . $row['addy3'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ' ' . $row['state'] . ' ' . $row['zip'] . '',
                'eventUrl' => '' . $row['event_url'] . '',
                'subName' => '' . $row['subName'] . '',
                'subEmail' => '' . $row['subEmail'],
            );
        }
        if ($row['d3'] != '0000-00-00') {
            $events[] = array('id' => '' . $row['id'] . '',
                'date' => '' . $ymd3 . ' ' . $row['start'] . '',
                'title' => '' . $row['event'] . '',
                'description' => '' . $row['descrip'] . '',
                'startTime' => '' . $row['start'] . '',
                'endTime' => '' . $row['end'] . '',
                'url' => 'event_details.html?id=' . $row['id'] . '&data=events',
                'location' => '' . $row['addy1'] . ' ' . $row['addy2'] . ' ' . $row['addy3'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ' ' . $row['state'] . ' ' . $row['zip'] . '',
                'eventUrl' => '' . $row['event_url'] . '',
                'subName' => '' . $row['subName'] . '',
                'subEmail' => '' . $row['subEmail'],
            );
        }
        if ($row['d4'] != '0000-00-00') {
            $events[] = array('id' => '' . $row['id'] . '',
                'date' => '' . $ymd4 . ' ' . $row['start'] . '',
                'title' => '' . $row['event'] . '',
                'description' => '' . $row['descrip'] . '',
                'startTime' => '' . $row['start'] . '',
                'endTime' => '' . $row['end'] . '',
                'url' => 'event_details.html?id=' . $row['id'] . '&data=events',
                'location' => '' . $row['addy1'] . ' ' . $row['addy2'] . ' ' . $row['addy3'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ' ' . $row['state'] . ' ' . $row['zip'] . '',
                'eventUrl' => '' . $row['event_url'] . '',
                'subName' => '' . $row['subName'] . '',
                'subEmail' => '' . $row['subEmail'],
            );
        }
        if ($row['d5'] != '0000-00-00') {
            $events[] = array('id' => '' . $row['id'] . '',
                'date' => '' . $ymd5 . ' ' . $row['start'] . '',
                'title' => '' . $row['event'] . '',
                'description' => '' . $row['descrip'] . '',
                'startTime' => '' . $row['start'] . '',
                'endTime' => '' . $row['end'] . '',
                'url' => 'event_details.html?id=' . $row['id'] . '&data=events',
                'location' => '' . $row['addy1'] . ' ' . $row['addy2'] . ' ' . $row['addy3'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ' ' . $row['state'] . ' ' . $row['zip'] . '',
                'eventUrl' => '' . $row['event_url'] . '',
                'subName' => '' . $row['subName'] . '',
                'subEmail' => '' . $row['subEmail'],
            );
        }
    }
}

var_dump($events);
```

Thoughts?  Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Have you checked if you are even able to receive the data from the db?

Comment: Check your database connection

Comment: The db connection works.  I'm pulling from the same db when I test locally (not one on my machine but on the server).

Comment: $get_result is populated? Have you tried to see what is inside?

Comment: Yes. on the server and locally I get this when I do a var_dump for $get_result

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(20) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(11) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: I think it's an issue with the array syntax.  or possibly the foreach?

Comment: @JohnProvidence Where do you fetch the data? Like in a while loop or so??

Comment: the foreach.  I'm using that to grab the data an push it into the event array. Then that array is gets encoded into JSON and saved to a file.

Comment: Off topic, but you need to tell your service provider to upgrade their PHP version -- 5.3 is no longer supported. Or better yet, switch to a service provider that does provide a more recent PHP version; don't reward the lazy companies that haven't bothered to upgrade in all the time since 5.4 came out more than three years ago.

Comment: ha ha. I agree. It's a company owned server. I have requested that we upgrade across the company to a more current server environment.  Sadly this has fallen on deaf ears. So, for the time being I'm stuck with php 5.3

Comment: It's not a problem of syntax between PHP versions; your code is perfectly valid for PHP 5.3 (and you'd be getting worse errors than an empty array if it wasn't). I agree with others that it's very likely to be a case of the DB query returning zero rows.

Comment: This issue wasn't with syntax, though it did deal with different versions of PHP.  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT was the culprit. Apparently is not compliant with PHP versions earlier then 5.4.  Removing that seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue wasn't with syntax, though it did deal with different versions of PHP.  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT was the culprit. Apparently is not compliant with PHP versions earlier then 5.4.  Removing that seems to have solved the problem.